# Setting up a frozen state Linux system

Tags: debian, security

I have some servers where, to improve privacy, I'd like to freeze the state of the system disk: that is, all logs and other disk writes to the system disk should be saved to RAM, the data used for whatever they're used for, then immediately wiped on reboot such that the system is guaranteed clean. (There are other disks that should *not* be frozen; only the system disk should be frozen)

What's the easiest way to achieve this? I considered using a tmpfs ramdisk to mount /var/log and /tmp although I'd be definitely missing a lot of other folders trying to mount one by one. There is also one program we'd like to back up logs of remotely, we were considering using `systemd_journal_remote` to do so which I assume would just forward the logs from the ramdisk as they are written.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you 3 possibilities:

1. To mount the root partition (/) as tmpfs in the /etc/fstab? /!\ Be careful!! /!\ Once done, you will not be able to reverse back to a read-write state, unless cold access to disk. (From other OS- almost physical access). So be VERY CAREFUL to not being blocked in an tmpfs state forever.
2. To build a live system OS from your running server, [for example using systemback](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-live-system-iso-for-your-ubuntu-based-linux-machines-using-systemback/). The advantage is that, at the end, it will gives you a live OS where modifications are not persistent across reboots.
3. Reproduce the Live System OS behaviour by making your system partition as [SquashFS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) (which is R/O), and combining with an union mount filesystem, such as UnionFS, OverlayFS, or aufs, to provide a read-write environment for your live Linux distribution (where disk writes will not persists across reboots). This is exactly the mechanism involved in "suggestion 2", and implemented by almost every live linux OS for providing this famous feature that you are looking for.

Hope it helps.